# How can I troubleshoot Facebook login in my Heroku production app?

Tags: javascript, facebook, heroku, devise, omniauth

I am having trouble diagnosing why my app's Facebook login flow, which worked fine in development, is failing when deployed to Heroku.

In brief, the flow works like this: Facebook's [javascript sdk web login code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/) is rendered onto website pages by a React component. When Facebook responds to a login request, it goes to the callback controller `/users/auth/facebook/callback`. Devise-omniauth lets Devise know to create a registration or session, and callback code in my app updates the view.

Here is the relevant output of `heroku logs`:

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback" for 23.243.29.123 at 2016-04-24 14:38:36 +0000
I, [2016-04-24T14:38:36.279311 #8]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook as JSON
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1 AND "users"."uid" = $2  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["provider", "facebook"], ["uid", "10239847019823470"]]
   (3.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (2.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = 'Fake Name' LIMIT 1
   (3.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to https://fakeapp.herokuapp.com/users/sign_up
```

So most things that I've seen covered in other questions have gone right:

1. I'm reaching Facebook, and FB is responding, so the Heroku Config Vars supplying the FACEBOOK_APP_ID and FACEBOOK_SECRET appear to be set successfully.
2. Facebook is transmitting user data to the omniauth callback
   controller, so I've got the right URL listed in Facebook's whitelist
   of callback URLs.
3. The omniauth controller seems to be properly
   parsing the uid and username from the hash that Facebook is sending,
   and trying to sign the user in.

And then the attempt to persist the user in the database is getting rolled back. Instead of creating or updating a record in the user table, my production app is saying 'User Exists,' and doing a ROLLBACK. (The users do NOT exist in the database, though. I've run `heroku run rails c` and `User.all()` does not include the user I'm trying to log in through Facebook.)

For comparison, here is a 'healthy' login from my development app:

```
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook as JSON
  User Load (6.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1 AND "users"."uid" = $2  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["provider", "facebook"], ["uid", "102983457091284357"]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (6.8ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = $5  [["last_sign_in_at", "2016-04-24 13:59:24.953190"], ["current_sign_in_at", "2016-04-25 13:33:48.756553"], ["sign_in_count", 55], ["updated_at", "2016-04-25 13:33:48.758631"], ["id", 8]]
   (5.3ms)  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 18.3ms)
```

This is `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

    def facebook
      @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

      if @user.persisted?
        respond_to do |format|
          format.json do
            sign_in @user
            return render :json => @user
          end
          format.html do
            sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
            set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
          end
        end
      else

        session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end

    end
end
```

Here is the User.from_omniauth method that the callback controller is calling to try to sign in the Facebook user:

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.username = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
      user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
    end
  end
```

So I've got no idea what's causing the attempt to persist the user to fail. Any thoughts on what's causing the failure, or just on how I can get better visibility into the problem than I can get just by viewing the Heroku app logs, would be very welcome.